# Twilio dial two numbers it plays voicemail for one number when the second call is still rings

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I am forwarding an Incoming call to two number, using TWIML dial, I have a problem that when the first number hit voicemail it starts playing voicemail while the other call is still ringing if both go to voicemail to plays both voicemail message.

```
<Response>
    <Dial record="record-from-ringing-dual"
    callerId="825689XXXX"
    recordingStatusCallback="https://recording.com"
    recordingStatusCallbackEvent="completed">
        <Number>123456XXXX</Number>
        <Number>78910XXXXX</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is here exactly. Can you explain further. What is the difference between one of the calls going to voicemail and both of them? What are you experiencing and what would you expect to experience?

Comment: @philnash I want the first number which picks up the phone to get connected to the incoming call. But if any of the calls go to VM, it started playing the VM message while the other call is still ringing.

Comment: Ah, multi-dialling with <Number> doesn’t work like that. Instead, you’ll need to make the calls using the REST API, you can then use answer machine detection on the outbound calls. Once you detect a call is answered by a human you can connect that to the original call and end any others still ringing.

Comment: @philnash Thanks, I was in the impression that if I add multiple <Number> , the call will get connected to the first picked up phone.

Comment: Yep, but when a voicemail picks up the phone that also counts as the first picked up phone.

Comment: @philnash Thanks. Sorry for all these questions. The strange thing is if voicemail pick is counted as the first pick, it still rings the other numbers

Comment: That is odd, you might want to contact [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) with that and supply some CallSids where it happened, it's not the correct behaviour.